# How can I return with a local variable in definition in Python?

Tags: python, return, definition, subtraction

I am trying to create a simple AI program which plays stick game. The problem is that I would like to subtract chosen stick from the total stick number. This simple code shows some error such as nonexisting value. I could not assign returning value for my values. Is there another way to subtracts value with functions?

```
import random
msg = input('Determine stick numbers:')
print('Stick number is determined as:', msg)

# First player move

def robot(stick):
    y = stick % 4
    if y==0:
        y=randint(1,3)
    mov=int(y)
    print('machine chose:', mov)
    total = stick-mov
    return total

def human(stick2):
    mov2= int(input('your turn:'))
    print('human chose:', mov2)
    total = stick2-mov2
    return total

players= {
    '1': robot,
    '2': human

        }

number1= input('Determine first player machine(1) or human(2):')
number2= input('Determine second player (1) or (2):')

player1=players[number1]
player2=players[number2]
print(player1, player2)

print('the game begins')

while True:
   player1(int(msg))
   if msg == 0: break

   print('remained sticks:', msg)
   player2(int(msg))
   print('remained sticks:', msg)
   if msg == 0: break
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Definition function does not return as subtracted value

Comment: looks fine to me.

Comment: what is "player2(int(msg))" supposed to do?

Comment: The syntax of print seems odd; shouldn't it be in the lines of print('text'+str(var)) or print('text {}'.format(var));

Comment: This syntax is correct and useful, you don't need to use str(value) if value is not a string.

Comment: Instead of pasting your whole code, please create a minimal example. In your case, that would be one function, one function call and one print which shows that the "return does not work". Most likely, when you create such minimal example, you will see the solution yourself. If you don't, ask here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sorry about the question. I asked in a wrong way. @Prune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your players are references functions:

```
players= {
    '1': robot,
    '2': human
        }
```

Later you call them `player1` and `player2`:

```
player1=players[number1]
player2=players[number2]
```

But when you use these functions *you don't do anything with the return value*:

```
player1(int(msg))
...
player2(int(msg))
```

So those functions return something, but you ignore the value.  You need to either print that return value or assign it to a variable so you can do something with the value later.

Since your return values are called `total` perhaps you want:

```
total = player1(int(msg))
print('new total:', total)
```

Comment: That makes sense, I will try it thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`return` *does* work, of course; it returns a value. However in your code you are not capturing that value and it is immediately thrown away.

It's really not clear what you want, but perhaps you want something like this:

```
msg = player1(int(msg))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understand now. Sorry about the question. I asked in a wrong way.